# Save Image from My Pictures Folder to Local App Folder in Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: image, binding, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm using a button to select an image from the Pictures folder, what I want is to save that selected image to the app's Local Storage in order to be able to show that image using binding in a GridView. Is this posible? How could I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it something like this:

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    await file.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
}
```