# How to save an image(avatar) in windows 8 metro to a location i choose instead of the user?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I can find plenty of examples using filepicker and letting the user decide where to save. What im trying to do is save a copy of the picture in a private storage folder of the metro app as a png file. The user picks the file but they don't need to choose where to store it...

I see this answer:

[Save Image from My Pictures Folder to Local App Folder in Windows 8 Metro App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569642/save-image-from-my-pictures-folder-to-local-app-folder-in-windows-8-metro-app)

which I'll try when I get home tonight, hoping i can just give the filepicker the storage location and bypass the user....does anybody have a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app can always store files in its [LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx) (as the link you mentioned shows) without requesting permission, but other locations will require the user to be involved.  [LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx) is pretty much the 'private storage folder for the app', so should meet your needs.

There are special folders, like Pictures Library, that you can declare as Capabilities in your app manifest and then the user essentially is granting access by virtue of having installed your app. The presumption here is the user opted into that access because they saw your app required that capability and they were ok with it.

Lastly, you could employ a scenario where the first time user runs, you request them to use the [FolderPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) to indicate where to store the files.  Once they've granted access to a location on the file system, that privilege can persists via the [AccessCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.aspx), so you don't have to ask again